# Combine a row in one coulmn with sql in Python

Tags: python, sql, list, row

I have created a sql file with python inserting some data from a imdb.txt file.

My code so fare:

```
import re
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('imdb1.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE imdb1 (ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Title, Rating)''')

x = open("ratings.list.txt","r")
movread = x.readlines()
x.close()



s = raw_input('Search: ').lower()
for ns in movread:


    if s in ns.lower():
        d = re.split('\s+',ns,4)
        Title = d[4].rstrip()
        Rating= d[3]

        list = [Title,Rating]

       # print list
        # Insert a row of data
        c.execute('INSERT INTO imdb1 ( Title, Rating) values (?, ?)', (list[0],list[1]))
        conn.commit()

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM imdb1 order by ROWID'):
       print row
```

This is the output when i print the row:

```
ROWID                       Title                            Rating

(1, u'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)', u'8.9')
(2, u'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)', u'8.8')
(3, u'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)', u'8.7')
(4, u'"5 Second Movies" (2007) {The Lord of the Rings and the Two Towers (#1.63)}', u'6.2')
```

I want to get all the titles in one list. Like this:

Note that the IMDB file is huge so this is like 0.1% of the output

```
 ( u'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)',
    u'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)',
    u'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)',
    u'"5 Second Movies" (2007) {The Lord of the Rings and the Two Towers (#1.63)}')
```

Can i somehow do this with sql or some basic python?

Comment: I have changed som thing in the post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you iterate through your rows the title is going to be an item you can reference from the tuple - if you just want to print it use

```
print row[1]
```

If you want to collect all titles in a python list,

```
titleList = []
....
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM imdb1 order by ROWID'):
    titleList.append(row[1])
```

You could also change your SELECT statement from "SELECT * ..." to "SELECT Title" if all you want is titles, which will make the Title value the only item in the row (at row[0]).

Caveat, I'm not sure about the column headings that are printing out there, or about the last row in the example of what you want which looks like more than just a title.